# Nginx and Apache running at same port

Tags: apache, nginx, web-deployment

there are projects running on apache and nginx.

as workaround, I set apache to run at port 80 while nginx at port 8000

How can I make nginx and apache to run the applications at similar port 80?

here is a simple scenario

- myserver.com/apache1
- myserver.com/apache2
- myserver.com:8000/nginx1
- myserver.com:8000/nginx2

is it possible to set a rule that if requests are for /nginx1 or /nginx2, apache will transfer request to nginx on port 80? or vice versa?

thanks.

Comment: You cannot have both nginx and apache listening on the same address:port. But you can configure apache  proxy for nginx and forward requests to address:8000 when the url is `/nginx1` or `/nginx2`. Or a redirect if you don't want to proxy.

Comment: Both servers can't listen on the same port in any case. You have two options 1) Proxy Pass and 2) Redirection.

Answer (score 0):

base from reply of alvits and Kashyap, I have no other choice but to keep on setting both webserver to different ports